# WebStorm doesn't recognize Vue Material Components HTML tags

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, vue-material

WebStorm recognize only `<md-list-item>` HTML tag from VueMaterial, the rest are not listed in the pop-up and after using them I get unknown HTML tag warning.

[image: WebStorm VueMaterial HTML tag]

my main.js looks like that:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
Vue.use(VueMaterial)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

I'm using WebStorm v2017.1.3

Comment: what version of WebStorm do u use? There is vue support only from 2017.1

Comment: Edited - 2017.1.3

Comment: Did u exclude node_modules directory in WebStorm Settings? I reckon Webstorm doesnt watch souce vue-material

Comment: it actually detected md-list-item from vue-material which is weird (it's showing it's right directory from node_modules)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I upgraded to WebStorm 2017.3 and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the custom tags haven't been added to your accepted html tag list. click on the tags and press `Alt`+`Enter` and then `Add {Custom Tag} to custom html tags`

What it's showing is the inspector trying to indicate malformed tag names, like `<sapn>` instead of `<span>`, you can disable this inspection as well but adding them to the custom tag list let's you indicate the tags you want while allowing it to continue to protect you.

You can also add custom directives like `v-bind:xxxxxx` or `:xxxxxx` to an accepted property list if the inspector has an issue with them.

Comment: Thats the case with webstorm <2017 right now it should work with vue tags out of the box, and it is but there are problems for vue material

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me on WebStorm 2021.2, and I tried to **File - Invalidate Caches**. After restarting WebStorm, it turns OK.

Comment: This worked for me in 2024 with Webstorm 2023.2 (Jul 21 2023)! Only thing I selected in the Invalidate Caches dialog was "Clear file system cache and Local History". Everything else was unselected.